# Sequelize model property undefined Express.js controller after auth with passport-jwt

Tags: express, sequelize.js, passport.js, passport-jwt

I am using **passport-jwt** to verify access to a given route in **express.js**, and then return a Sequelize model to the final controller. The code looks like:

The auth strategy:

```
const passportStrategy = passport => {
    const options = {
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey: config.auth.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
    };

    passport.use(
        new Strategy(options, async (payload, done) => {
            try {
                const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: payload.email }});
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, {
                        user
                    });
                }
                return done(null, false);
            }
            catch (error) {
                return done(error, false)
            }
        })
    );
};
```

The route with the auth middleware

```
router.get('/:user_id/psy', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), patientsController.getPatientPsy);
```

The controller function

```
const getPatientPsy = async (req, res) => {
    const authenticatedUser = req.user;

    if (authenticatedUser.userType !== "patient") {
       res.status(500).send("Big time error");
    }
}
```

If I `console.log(authenticatedUser)` in the **getPatientPsy()** controller it successfully prints the Sequelize model with it's *dataValues* and so on, but when I try to access any property, be it *userType* or any other it consistently returns *undefined*.

In the passport-jwt authentication once a User has been found that matches the extracted JWT token, afaik it is returned synchronously and made it available in the *req.user* object, and I can print it with console.log, but why can't I access the model's properties?

I've tried to make the **getPatientPsy()** controller a sync function but it doesn't work either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All right this is embarrassing, by default Passport.js returns the done(null, user) in the *req.user* property, and since I am returning `{ user }`, I had to access through *req.user.user*.